# $ bin/rails routesしたときの(.:format)とは

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsを勉強中で、こちらのドキュメントを読んでいます。
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

[チャプター5](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running)で、`$ bin/rails routes`したときの`(.:format)`が何を表しているのかわからないので教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

まずお使いのドキュメントですが[日本語訳版](https://railsguides.jp/)も存在しているので参考にどうぞ。

で、質問されている`/articles(.:format)`の`(.format)`の部分ですが、[同ガイド](https://railsguides.jp/routing.html#%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AE%E5%89%B2%E3%82%8A%E5%BD%93%E3%81%A6)にも書かれているようにRailsのルーティングにおいて`()`で囲まれている部分は必須ではないパラメータとなります。

つまり、ユーザーは求めるリソース形式に応じて `/articles` の他に `/articles.json` や `/articles.xml` のように拡張子を指定することでそれをすることが出来るわけです。
具体的な例としては[この辺り](https://railsguides.jp/action_controller_overview.html#xml%E3%81%A8json%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E6%8F%8F%E7%94%BB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)とかで出てくるので参考に。

(私はほとんど&長らくRails触ったことがないので誤りがあったらごめんなさい)